# Why does my iTunes play count indicate certain tracks have been listened to hundreds of times when I've only played them a few times?

Tags: itunes

My iTunes play count is indicating that I have played certain tracks hundreds of times which is incorrect as I have only played these tracks 10 or 15 times. It also seems to have done so only with one or two artists and on a couple occassions where they have recorded the same song. Why does this happen and can it be corrected?

Answer (score 1):

Playcounts are embedded persistently in the media files.
When you share audio files, you also share their play count.